# Static Library classes not getting compiled into apk

Tags: java, android, makefile

I am currently trying to build an application with the use of Android.mk. The application depends on a Android Library which I have exported to .jar file which is located in the application' libs folder. After building the application it is clear that the Library' classes isn't included in the apk - what have i done wrong?

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := StaticLibrary

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-subdir-java-files)

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += $(LOCAL_PATH)/res
LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR += packages/apps/StaticLibrary/res

LOCAL_MANIFEST_FILE := AndroidManifest.xml
LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := CustomerService
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform

LOCAL_PROGUARD_FLAG_FILES := proguard.flags

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := StaticLibrary/staticlibrary.jar

include $(BUILD_MULTI_PREBUILT)
```

Comment: .so files in external .jar files are not copied to your .apk file. It's a limitation of the ADT. You'll need to manually copy the .so file to the /libs folder of your project.

Comment: The external .jar file doesn't contain any .so files.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Misunderstood the issue.